# Send POST message through .php in swift 2.0

Tags: php, swift, http, post

I have a .php file with this inside it:

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
<?php

//create short variable names
$message_txt=strip_tags($_POST['message_txt']."\n\n".json_encode($_POST), "<p>");

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: thing<emailaddress@email.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Website <email@website.com>';

mail($toaddress, "THING Website", $message_txt, $headers);
```

I would like to take text from a textView and send it through this php. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: That is not quiet simple but I can give yo an answer;)

Comment: Write me back if you got any questions, I can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need this code in swift in order to parse the variables to the php file. I will show you the code and will explain it to you afterwards step by step.

**Here the code for Swift:**

```
func HttpRequest() {
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://yourUrl.de/yourPhpScript.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "Message=\(textView.text)";

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }


        do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary



        if let parseJSON = json {
            var resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
            print("result: \(resultValue)")

            if(resultValue=="Success")
            {
                // If result from php is success, do something...
            }


            else
            {
                // if result from php failed, do something...
            }


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {


                //Display alert with confirmation.
                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Your message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                let OkAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){ action in


                }

                myAlert.addAction(OkAction)
                self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);

            });

        }

        } catch {
            // report error
        }

    }
    task.resume()

}
```

**Lets start with the explanation:**

1. In the first line you have a string referring to your .php file which might be on the server
2. `request.HTTPMethod` is set to `POST` because you want to post something to the php file
3. Now the postString: From my example there is a variable called "Message" in the php file and with the "=" you simply assign it a value which is "textView.text" in my case, you can append other variables as well by putting and "&" directly after it
4. Then there is a bit of code, the request is ASYNC of course because you don't want to block your main thread, this is very important
5. In the `if let parseJSON` will be the values of the re-parsed values from the php script, which will be available if the ASYNC returned a value, don't put it before it won't be available
6. In your php file you could simply parse back a variable named "status" to show on success or on failure and you can handle that back in swift then

**Now the php file:**

```
<?php 

// If you want to connect to a server you have to do that
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$passwordServer = "";
$dbname = "";


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $passwordServer, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (isset ($_POST["Message"]){
    $YourMessageFromSwift = $_POST["Message"];
}

// do what you want using php

$returnValue["status"] = "Success";
echo json_encode($returnValue);

mysqli_close($verbindung);
?>
```

**Explanation:**

1. Firstly create the connection to your server (this is optional)
2. Then use isset to evaluate if the variable is passed correctly
3. Remember that the `$_POST["Message"]` are the same as in the swift file
4. In the last step you could parse the status with json_encode

Hope this helps all of you:)

Comment: Thanks so much for this reply. Do I need to add a line in the .php to email the message to me? Do I combine me original php with this new one or should I just replace it?

Comment: I didn't try out your php code but if it was working you can combine them of course. You can add whatever you want in your php file.

Comment: normally when I use my old php file the only text I get in the email is `[]`. I haven't tried your code with it yet though. @Anokrize

Comment: Yeah can't seem to get it to work. Could just be me though.

Comment: Do you have problems with my answer or your php script?